# Since the UN charter is amendable easily. What is stopping nations from amending it to have less UN obligations?

Tags: treaty

It seems like a pretty intuitive thing to do. They could even invalidate various treaties they have signed.

Answer (score 3):

### The [UN charter](https://www.un.org/en/about-us/un-charter#:%7E:text=Since%20the%20UN%27s%20founding%20in,1963%2C%201965%2C%20and%201973.) is really hard to amend

It requires approval by two-thirds of its member states, and ratification by two-thirds of its member states, including in both cases by the five permanent members of the security council (the USA, the UK, Russia, China, and France). It's happened a total of 3 times, in each case, for completely non-controversial reasons.